# SAS: Can't understand the use of '+1' in this code?

Tags: input, sas

I was using the following code to read data in SAS, the given is the code that I tried

```
data libcards;
infile datalines;
input name $11. birthdate date9. issuedate mmddyy10.;
datalines;
A. Jones     1jan60    9-15-03
M. Rincon   05OCT1949 02-29-2000
Z. Grandage 18mar1988 10-10-2002
K. Kaminaka 29may2001 01-24-2003
;
run;
```

Needless to say the dates were not read in correctly, except the ones on the first row. Then I changed the format but it still didn't work. Then I looked up the solution, and this is the code that was given.

```
 data libcards;
 infile datalines;
 input name $11. +1 birthdate date9. +1 issuedate mmddyy10.;
 datalines;
 A. Jones     1jan60    9-15-03
 M. Rincon   05OCT1949 02-29-2000
 Z. Grandage 18mar1988 10-10-2002
 K. Kaminaka 29may2001 01-24-2003
 ;
 run;
```

And this code works perfectly. I can see that the difference is the  "+1" part, but I don't understand how it's working. The book that I am using has no explanation about it.

Can anyone tell me what's going on here? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not familiar with SAS, but it looks like the +1 accounts for the blank space between the columns.

Comment: @KenWhite It's called pointer control in SAS there are line and column pointers .  +n advances the column pointer.  You can also back up.

Comment: @data_null: So I guessed right. :-) Thanks for the info; I'll tuck it away for future reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`+n` moves the pointer n columns, in this case, just 1 to the right to read the data. [This](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146292.htm) SAS doc page may help with more details.

Answer (score 2):

To read this file you can use a combination of formatted input (for the first field) and "format modified" list input for the other two fields.
name : format. 
tells SAS to use list input with a specific informat.  You can also do same by using INFORMAT statement to associate the informat to the variable.

```
data libcards;
   infile datalines;
   input name $11. birthdate :date9. issuedate :mmddyy10.;
   datalines;
A. Jones     1jan60    9-15-03
M. Rincon   05OCT1949 02-29-2000
Z. Grandage 18mar1988 10-10-2002
K. Kaminaka 29may2001 01-24-2003
;
run;
proc print;
   run;
```

You may want to associate a FORMAT with the date variables.

[image]